# Java upload files to remote linux server WITHOUT ftp or scp

Tags: java, file-upload

I am trying to write a program in java to upload some files from my local environment to a remote server. I cannot use FTP because there is no FTP server installed on that instance. Also port 22 is closed so I can't use scp either.

Is there any other way to approach this?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: So what port *is* open, and what protocol are you supposed to use to upload the files?

Comment: So what is installed? Apache, PHP? How do you access there?

Comment: It highly depends on what your remote server is capable of.  But HTTP could be a safe bet since the port is usually opened.

Comment: can you run your code on the server too ? then you can write a simple client/server program.

Answer (score 1):

You need something on the serverside, a program, which is waiting for your file. You can't just send something there.

An open port is always a program running, waiting for a connect.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of possible protocols are rsync and WebDav.  But at the end of the day I recommend one of two options. Get ssh installed, or use rsync.

Talk to the unix admin and work something out.

Answer (score 0):

Even linux servers sometimes use smb/cifs (the Microsoft technique to share files and folders) to publish data. The samba team provides a 100% Java library to access those: http://jcifs.samba.org/