# to upload file on oracle server directory using java and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to upload a .pdf file on oracle server directory(not table) using java and hibernate.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has nothing to do with your current problem, and neither will it be useful in this context. Hibernate is meant to access logical database objects like tables, views, etc. and not physical database objects like directories or files on the server. Therefore, I am going to assume that your current requirement is to place uploaded PDF files onto a directory that is accessible by an Oracle database server process, with the database server located on a remote machine.

In this context, you should use a file transfer protocol like FTP, SSH(SFTP), SMB, or any other suitable protocol, to transfer the uploaded file to the directory. There are several other related questions on this topic:

- [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)
- [Running commands over ssh with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570450/running-commands-over-ssh-with-java)
- [FTP upload via sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705600/ftp-upload-via-sockets)
- [upload files to remote linux server WITHOUT ftp or scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867516/java-upload-files-to-remote-linux-server-without-ftp-or-scp)

You'll need to first choose a supported protocol (on the database server) that you wish to use, and then build a solution around that.